# How to modify submitted file client-side in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file, flash

I want to modify the file submitted by user on the client side, before it reaches my server. To modify it I want to use Flash applet that would communicate with JavaScript.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="id_file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Is it possible to do it? If yes, I would appreciate any tips how should it be done :)

Should I convert it to string? Or maybe JS comes with some functions to make such operations easier?

```
$( "form" ).change(function(x) {
    //pass file input to Flash applet
    x.preventDefault();
    flashApplet.proceed($('#id_file').value);
});

function callback(modified_file) {
    // Flash applet has modified the file
    // Now submit the form with a new, modified file
    $('#id_file').value = modified_file;
    trigger_submit();
}
```

The file can be either a video, an audio or an image.

Comment: Why not just set the new value from within the flash applet?

Comment: How? Can I just assign byte array to the `<input>` value?

Comment: Just try it! That's what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a submit button, instead use a normal button disguised to look like a submit button, and then you can check when the button is clicked, do your stuff, then submit the form via javascript by using

```
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

I would replace your current html with:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
  <input type="file">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then js:

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
  //do your flash stuff
}​;

function callback(){
  //here we submit the form
  document.getElementById("myform").submit();
  // because the file itself has been modified, this is all we need to do.
}
```

Basically, use a false submit button, to do what you want first.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately, this does not resolve the issue. The problem is not WHEN to submit. The problem is HOW to MODIFY input file.

Comment: Oh. That could maybe be made a little clearer. Do you already have a flash function? If so, could you post it please?

Comment: I updated the code a little. Why would Flash function matter? I just want to replace original value of file input with a new file.

Comment: the flash function matters because I need to see whether you are accepting any arguments, and how you are attempting to communicate with the js.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to hear from you xD How should I communicate with Flash in order to be able to replace the file field value. Ideally, I would accept one argument (original file) and return one argument to the callback function (modified file).